# AngularJS apply class to multiple buttons in mutual exclusive way

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, with a `jQuery` background, and still trying to get into *Angular thinking* . 
I've several `button`s like :

```
<button class="btn active">btn1</button>
<button class="btn">btn2</button>
...
<button class="btn">btnN</button>
```

With `jQuery` to accomplish my goal, that is to have `active` `class` only on one `button` at time, I would do

**jQuery**

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(){
 $(this).siblings().removeClass('active')
        .end()
        .addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active{ ... }
```

but I did not find out a **general** way to do this in Angular. I found a solution for 3 buttons, but it gets rude, especially if I have multiple `route` in my application.

In particular, now the solution I'm using is:

**markup**

```
<li class="start" ng:click="selected = 1" ng-class="{active: selected == 1}">
 <a href="#contenuti> </a>
</li>
<li class="start" ng:click="selected = 2" ng-class="{active: selected == 2}">
 <a href="#utenti> </a>
</li>
<li class="start" ng:click="selected = 3" ng-class="{active: selected == 3}">
 <a href="#messaggi> </a> 
</li>
```

**In the CONTROLLER** ( for bootstrap settings)

```
switch($location.path()){
 case '/contenuti/plot': 
  $scope.selected = 1;
  break;
 case '/utenti': 
  $scope.selected = 2;
  break;
 case '/messaggi': 
  $scope.selected = 3;
  break;
}
```

which is a solution that I don't really love, I don't think is a really good solution. 
Thanks in advance for helping.

jQuery solution Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HS4d6/

Comment: AngularJS is data-driven. *Usually* you should forget about the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to **Angular world** -- it is bit different than jQuery. But you will love it!

There are a lot of goodies in Angular, but the queen among them is `directive`!

Here is a scaffold of solution that is quite generic and works without worrying about current scope at all. It basically uses directive initialization function to inter-instances communication. Just give me a shout if you have problems extending it to your particular needs.

```
app.directive('selectable', function(){

    var selected;

    var unselect = function(element) {
        element.removeClass('selected');
    }

    var select = function(element) {
        if (selected){
            unselect(selected);
        }
        selected = element;
        element.addClass('selected');
    }

    return {

        link : function(scope, element, attrs){

            element.on('click', function(){
                select(element);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/w93PulINaPkBVFoOUBdo?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: What can be model driven, you have moved it to a directive and done something similar what you would do in jquery, which I think is not the angular way. The better way would using something what @Mathew has suggested or the user is already doing

Comment: @Chandermani button does strictly belong to the view-world (DOM world) -- can you agree with it? My solution is just a **scaffold**, a **seed** -- it should work as an inspiration. It can be easily modified to be model driven: just `$watch` a value passed by `=` (or `$observe` `@`). OP wanted a solution to work for: *especially if I have multiple route in my application*. How are you going to use `ng-repeat` on multiple routes?

Comment: @Chandermani one more question: why using jQuery selector could be better than this -- please provide some context?

Comment: I think this can be a valid solution. What I'm thinking is if it is really worth it; the number of code lines compared to the goal, is not so "cheap" and I was thinking if there is a way without use jqlight DOM manipulation, practically without `on()` and use `ng-` instead. 
Anyway thanks for all explaination and everything!

Comment: @steo `ng-click` works almost in the same way -- it just attaches a callback to the `click` event. If you want to trigger an action you can pass an expression to the directive by setting `selected=expression` (in the html markup - exactly as with `ng-click`) and in the directive just return: `{ link : ..., scope : {selected : "&"}}`. I do not think there is that many lines of code -- moreover *selecting* works in a constant time, while your jQuery solutoin needs *O(number of buttons)* and with *ng-repeat* it re-runs in every `$digest`-cycle and needs as well linear time.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak i was talking about him using `$scope.selected` variable to select the active element. But instead of using selected a better variable\object that describe the context of the UI element.

Answer (score 2):

Since all your buttons seem to be very similar, you could use an ng-repeat like so:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="button in buttons" data-ng-class="{ active: button.url == location.path() }></li>
```

And then your controller would be this:

```
function myController($scope....){
    $scope.location = $location;

    $scope.buttons = [
        { url: '/contenuti/plot' },
        { url: '/utenti' },
        { url: '/messaggi' }
    ];
}
```

It'd be easy to add more buttons this way and have them automatically work. Clearly modify to suit your own needs.